# How can I get stocks' historical high, low, and close prices?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

How can I retrieve historical stock prices in Google Sheets?

I'd like to be able to return historical  weekly and monthly high, low and close prices.

Answer (score 1):

The  [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en-GB) function's **interval** argument supports `daily` or `weekly` only.  It does not support monthly.

For example, to return historical weekly high, low, and close prices, use the following formula:

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","all", "1/1/2020","2/17/2020",7),"select Col1, Col3, Col4, Col5")
```

*(Replace your values accordingly)*

Functions used:

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB)
- [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en-GB)